# Relative Layout Center Not working with Dividing line view

Tags: android

I can't seem to figure out why I can't horizontally center the datepicker and timepicker under the dividing line when i put it's layout_width to match_parent.

When i put the dividing line's layout_width to wrap_content, the pickers center horizontally. But the line doesn't fill the relative view.

I'm just confused, i don't understand what's going on.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <!-- Dividing Line -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/BlueLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="@color/holo_blue_light" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/DatePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/BlueLine"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/TimePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/BlueLine"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/DatePicker" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any specific reason for using Relative Layout? I think you would be able to accomplish the desired layout much easier with Linear Layout - vertical for the blue line and another linear layout parent element which can contain the datepicker and timepicker. Then horizontal for the datepicker and timepicker within their parent layout element.

Comment: I have it working using a linear layout but I read that a relative layout would be more efficient. Am I wrong?

Comment: I don't think it would make a significant difference, based on the number and type of elements you have in the layout.